# PowerShell cannot find files ending in .EXE

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a PowerShell script program that is suppose to find a file on my computer and once it is found display results. The file in question can be the full name or a partial. If the file doesn't exist a message with output that.

Problem: It seems that files/application ending in .msi will be found but if the files/application ends in .exe it will not be found. How do I fix this?

```
$ADObjects = Get-ADComputer -filter {(name -like "Your PC Name goes here")};

$ADObjects | ForEach {
    $computerName = $_.name;
    Write-Output $computerName;
    $Versions = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $computerName| Where-Object {$_.name -like "FireFox"});   # Finds all versions of the program

    $Count = ($Versions | Measure-object).count;
    if ($Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Output "$computerName does not have this application.";
    }
    else {
    
        Write-Output $Versions;

        #$Versions.unistall();    # Uncommenting this line will uninstall the versions listed by the line above
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to look for any files

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: You are looking for installed programs and not files. When it comes to installed programs, there appears to be no single source of truth. Even the control panel can lie. I suggest you look for posts that tackle that issue specifically. This is an issue that has plagued Windows for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is to find files that endes with exe to add to your line of code

```
Where-Object { $_.Name -Match '.*\.exe$' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to find all the .exe files in the Program Files folder of your computer:

```
$gci *.exe -path 'C:\Program Files\' -recurse
```

You can refine this to search only for files that contain the word "Firefox".

HOWEVER, it appears that you are not really trying to find files, but WIN32 products.  They are not the same thing.  If you don't know what you are looking for, it's going to be awfully hard to tell you how to look.

Answer (score 0):

Get-package is faster and will list both msi and program installs.  Msi installs can be piped to uninstall-package.  You'd have to use invoke-command to run it remotely in parallel.

```
invoke-command comp1,comp1,comp3 { get-package *firefox* }
```